# Understanding into() to resolve constant generic expression type mismatch in nightly Rust

Tags: generics, rust, types

I'd like to understand the following compiler error while using `feature(generic_const_expr)` in nightly Rust.  As I am still learning Rust, it could very well be due to lack of my understanding of the compiler, or due to a bug from the feature still being incomplete, or both.

I am implementing my own units package to help me carry compile-time checks using dimensional analysis.  Below is a minimal version generating the compiler error.

#### `lib.rs`:

A quantity with dimensions is represented as a struct with generic constant integers specifying the power of Time (`T`) and Length (`L`).  The actual numerical value is stored as `f64`:

```rust
#![feature(generic_const_exprs)]
#![allow(incomplete_features)]

#[derive(Clone, Copy)]
pub struct Quant<const T: i8, const L: i8>(pub f64);
```

I want to multiply two such quantities so I implement the `Mul` trait which uses generic constant expressions to produce a new quantity with different dimensions:

```rust
use std::ops::Mul;
impl<const T1: i8, const L1: i8, const T2: i8, const L2: i8> Mul<Quant<T2, L2>> for Quant<T1, L1>
    where Quant<{T1 + T2}, {L1 + L2}>: Sized {

    type Output = Quant<{T1 + T2}, {L1 + L2}>;

    fn mul(self, other: Quant<T2, L2>) -> Quant<{T1 + T2}, {L1 + L2}> {
        Quant::<{T1 + T2}, {L1 + L2}>(self.0 * other.0)
    }

}
```

#### `main.rs`:

Here I define a helper function to compute a speed from a distance and a frequency.  The compiler complains that `dist*freq` is of type `...::::{impl#0}::Output::{constant#0}...` which doesn't match the expected type `Quant::<-1, 1>`.  A solution is to call `into()`.  But I do not understand why.

```
use my_project::*;

fn get_my_speed(dist: Quant::<0, 1>, freq: Quant::<-1, 0>) -> Quant::<-1, 1> {
    (dist*freq)//.into()
}
```

```
fn main() {

    let my_length = Quant::<0, 1>(5.4);     //5.4 meters
    let my_frequency = Quant::<-1, 0>(1.2); //1.2 hertz
    let my_speed = get_my_speed(my_length, my_frequency);
    
    println!("Speed: {}", my_speed.0);  //expecting 4.5

}
```

Even more confusingly, if I move all the definitions out of the `lib.rs` file into the `main.rs` the compiler is able to compile without the `.into()` without any errors.  Why?

Comment: I'm guessing this is either a typo or something fixed in the newest nightly, because I can't reproduce it. https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0094e6ea4757be9df8ea2dd6198820c3

Comment: Yeah, I think it works in the playground because it is equivalent to putting all the definitions in one file.  I seem to run into the compiler error only when the definitions and function call are in two separate files (`lib.rs` and `main.rs`) as I outline in my post above.

Comment: Okay, I see what you mean now. This is most likely a compiler bug. You should file a bug on rust's github (or find an existing one). Another fix I found is assigning it to a variable and then returning the variable.

Comment: Thanks!  I'm new to this: I just file the bug here https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues?

Comment: I found this, which looks to be the same https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/114406

Comment: So the real issue is that the function needs to be defined in a crate with `generic_const_exprs` enabled.

Comment: Your link to the issues tracker and your conclusion about generic_const_exprs solved my problem.  Would you convert your comments into an answer that I can accept?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug with `generic_const_exprs` that sometimes happens when:

1. You use `generic_const_exprs` in one crate.
2. You try to use the generic code in another crate that doesn't have the `generic_const_exprs` feature enabled.

There's already an issue for this on Rust's GitHub: [`generic_const_exprs` and generics inferring lead to false impls resolving across files](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/114406)

Right now, you can fix this by enabling the feature in both crates, but hopefully this is fixed by the time the feature is complete in nightly.